# API blueprint MSON to define valid Attribute values?

Tags: validation, attributes, apiblueprint, mson

Consider this excerpt from https://github.com/apiaryio/mson#example-1 ...

### Example 1

A simple `object` structure and its associated JSON expression.

MSON

`- id: 1
- name: A green door
- price: 12.50
- tags: home, green`

---

Let's say I would like to define **valid values** for the `name` attribute.  Consider a context of API testing with a tool such as Dredd.  We may need to define what are the expected/valid `name` values in response to GET'ing this resource, or else something is probably broken and this test step should fail.

And/or, if creating/updating a resource of this type, we may need to define what `name` values are valid/accepted.  Is this currently possible to define in MSON?
(I believe this *can* be done in a JSON schema, which makes me hopeful for MSON support.)

Following is an example API Blueprint resource to illustrate how this would be used...

```
# Thing ID [/api/thing/id]

# List Thing ID attributes [GET]

    + Response 200

    + Attributes
        + href (string)
        + make (string)
        + model (string)
        + version (string)

    + Body

            {"href":"/api/thing/id","make":"BrandX","model":"SuperThingy","version":"10.1"}
```

In the above example, there are 3 known/accepted/valid values for the `model` attribute: `CoolThingy`, `AwesomeThingy`, and `MLGThingy`

Can we represent this resource in MSON, such that...

- Apiary (or other rendered) API documentation consumers can easily know what `model` values to expect?
- Dredd processes and passes/fails the `model` value in the response to a GET to this resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MSON you can use enum, see the example below.

- `name` (enum[string])

  - `joe` (default)
  - `ben`
  - `mark`

Comment: Thank you!  I had arrived at the same answer and was just about to answer my own question. :)